# WordPress doesn't identify the subfolder

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, robots.txt

I have a subfolder with a separate WordPress running on it. When I click on a link which should lead to the destination in the new website (the subfolder) it reads everything except the mentioned subfolder.

For example, my address is `https://www.example.com` and when I click the link, it should take to `https://www.example.com/TheSubfolder/rest` of the address. but it doesn't identify the subfolder. When I hover over the link it shows `https://www.example.com/rest` of the address.

How to solve this problem so everything shows correctly?

This is my .htaccess content. "old-parsik" is the subfolder which i am talking about.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 
 RewriteBase /old-parsik/ 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /old-parsik/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sounds like you've perhaps not set the appropriate SITE_URL and HOME_URL in the WordPress config?

Comment: I double checked on that, it shows as subfolder.

Comment: Have you reset _permalinks_?

Comment: @MrWhite yes absolutely.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of the apache configuration file for the second site and check that it's enabled. If you don't have a separate configuration file, that's the problem.

Comment: "my address is https://www.example.com and when I click the link, it should take to https://www.example.com/TheSubfolder/rest" - Why should it, when WordPress is installed in the subdirectory? Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the document root? (I'm assuming the `.htaccess` file you've posted is in the subdirectory?)

Answer (score 0):

Log into the Wordpress backend (https://www.example.com/Thesubfolder/wp-admin and then in the Dashboard go to Settings - > General
Change the Wordpress Address and Site Address to https://www.example.com/Thesubfolder

Comment: the OP says in a comment above "I double checked on that, it shows as subfolder."